# oracle self join performance issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to find the parent serial number. Below is what my data looks like.

```
ROW_NUMBER  PLAN_LEVEL   PARENT_ORDER    CHILD_ORDER SERIAL_NUMBER
1           1            P1              X1          S
2           1            P2              X2          S1
3           2            X2              N1          S2
4           3            N1              Y1          S4
5           3            N1              Y1          S5
6           2            X2              N1          S22
7           3            N1              Y1          S6
8           3            N1              Y2          S7
9           1            P2              X3          S8
10          2            X3              N1          S33
11          3            N1              Y1          S9
```

Since same parent order/child order combination exists at different level, I need to consider row_number and plan_level also to get the correct parent serial number.

Expected result:

```
ROW_NUMBER  PLAN_LEVEL   PARENT_ORDER    CHILD_ORDER SERIAL_NUMBER   PARENT_SERIAL_NUMBER
1           1            P1              X1          S
2           1            P2              X2          S1
3           2            X2              N1          S2              S1
4           3            N1              Y1          S4              S2
5           3            N1              Y1          S5              S2
6           2            X2              N1          S22             S1
7           3            N1              Y1          S6              S22
8           3            N1              Y2          S7              S22
9           1            P2              X3          S8
10          2            X3              N1          S33             S8
11          3            N1              Y1          S9              S33
```

I'm able to achieve this by using below sql but it is running for very very long time.

```
WITH t AS
  (SELECT 1 row_NUMBER,
    1 PLAN_Level,
    'P1' parent_ORDER,
    'X1' child_ORDER,
    'S' serial_NUMBER
  FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 1, 'P2', 'X2', 'S1' FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 2, 'X2', 'N1', 'S2' FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 3, 'N1', 'Y1', 'S4' FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 3, 'N1', 'Y1', 'S5' FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 2, 'X2', 'N1', 'S22' FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 3, 'N1', 'Y1', 'S6' FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 3, 'N1', 'Y2', 'S7' FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 9, 1, 'P2', 'X3', 'S8' FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 10, 2, 'X3', 'N1', 'S33' FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, 3, 'N1', 'Y1', 'S9' FROM DUAL
  )
SELECT T.*,
  (SELECT T2.SERIAL_NUMBER
  FROM T T2
  WHERE T2.ROW_NUMBER=
    (SELECT MAX(ROW_NUMBER) MAX_ROW
    FROM T T1
    WHERE T1.CHILD_ORDER= T.PARENT_ORDER
    AND T1.PLAN_LEVEL   = T.PLAN_LEVEL-1
    AND T1.ROW_NUMBER   < T.ROW_NUMBER
    )
  ) PARENT_SERIAL_NUMBER
FROM T
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER,
  PLAN_LEVEL;
```

"AND T1.ROW_NUMBER   < T.ROW_NUMBER" is causing the performance issue. If I comment out this condition then it completes within few seconds.

Comment: What indexing is available on this table? Can you provide the DDL for the table please.

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating the following indexes:

- Index on (CHILD_ORDER, PLAN_LEVEL, ROW_NUMBER): to improve the performance of the subquery which filters rows based on CHILD_ORDER, PLAN_LEVEL, and ROW_NUMBER.
- Index on (ROW_NUMBER): to help with the sorting operation in the ORDER BY clause.

e.g:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_child_plan_row ON your_table (CHILD_ORDER, PLAN_LEVEL, ROW_NUMBER);
CREATE INDEX idx_row_number ON your_table (ROW_NUMBER);
```

If you run Oracle 12c or later you can also experiment with using OUTER APPLY (or a "lateral join") to run the subquery, here are 2 variants to consider:

```
SELECT
     T.*, oa.*
FROM your_table T
OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT T2.SERIAL_NUMBER as PARENT_SERIAL_NUMBER
        FROM your_table T2
        WHERE T2.ROW_NUMBER = (
                SELECT MAX(ROW_NUMBER) MAX_ROW
                FROM your_table T1
                WHERE T1.CHILD_ORDER = T.PARENT_ORDER
                    AND T1.PLAN_LEVEL = T.PLAN_LEVEL - 1
                    AND T1.ROW_NUMBER < T.ROW_NUMBER
                )
        ) oa
ORDER BY
      ROW_NUMBER
    , PLAN_LEVEL
```

**OR**

```
SELECT
     T.*, oa.*, T2.SERIAL_NUMBER as PARENT_SERIAL_NUMBER
FROM your_table T
OUTER APPLY (
                SELECT MAX(ROW_NUMBER) MAX_ROW
                FROM your_table T1
                WHERE T1.CHILD_ORDER = T.PARENT_ORDER
                    AND T1.PLAN_LEVEL = T.PLAN_LEVEL - 1
                    AND T1.ROW_NUMBER < T.ROW_NUMBER
        ) oa
LEFT JOIN your_table T2 on oa.max_row = T2.row_number
ORDER BY
      T.ROW_NUMBER
    , T.PLAN_LEVEL
```

see these working in [this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CzmlQshJ)

I suggest you compare explain plans for your query (and the alternatives) before & after adding the indexes.

Comment: Hi Paul, after creating indexes, it is running fast now. I will check other 2 options. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hierarchical query (since you have a hierarchical relationship in the data) and filter to find the maximum row number using the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function. That only requires you to `SELECT` from the table once (eliminating the self-joins):

```sql
SELECT row_number,
       plan_level,
       parent_order,
       child_order,
       serial_number,
       parent_serial_number,
       parent_row_number
FROM   (
  SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT row_number AS row_number,
         CONNECT_BY_ROOT plan_level AS plan_level,
         CONNECT_BY_ROOT parent_order AS parent_order,
         CONNECT_BY_ROOT child_order AS child_order,
         CONNECT_BY_ROOT serial_number AS serial_number,
         CASE LEVEL WHEN 2 THEN serial_number END AS parent_serial_number,
         CASE LEVEL WHEN 2 THEN row_number END AS parent_row_number,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CONNECT_BY_ROOT row_number ORDER BY row_number DESC) AS rn
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE  (LEVEL = 1 AND CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1)
  OR     LEVEL = 2
  CONNECT BY
         PRIOR parent_order = child_order
  AND    PRIOR plan_level = plan_level + 1
  AND    PRIOR row_number > row_number
)
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY row_number;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (row_number, plan_level, parent_order, child_order, serial_number) AS
  SELECT 1, 1, 'P1', 'X1', 'S' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 1, 'P2', 'X2', 'S1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 2, 'X2', 'N1', 'S2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 3, 'N1', 'Y1', 'S4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 3, 'N1', 'Y1', 'S5' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 2, 'X2', 'N1', 'S22' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 3, 'N1', 'Y1', 'S6' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 3, 'N1', 'Y2', 'S7' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 9, 1, 'P2', 'X3', 'S8' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 10, 2, 'X3', 'N1', 'S33' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, 3, 'N1', 'Y1', 'S9' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ROW_NUMBER | PLAN_LEVEL | PARENT_ORDER | CHILD_ORDER | SERIAL_NUMBER | PARENT_SERIAL_NUMBER | PARENT_ROW_NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | P1 | X1 | S | *null* | *null* |
| 2 | 1 | P2 | X2 | S1 | *null* | *null* |
| 3 | 2 | X2 | N1 | S2 | S1 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 | N1 | Y1 | S4 | S2 | 3 |
| 5 | 3 | N1 | Y1 | S5 | S2 | 3 |
| 6 | 2 | X2 | N1 | S22 | S1 | 2 |
| 7 | 3 | N1 | Y1 | S6 | S22 | 6 |
| 8 | 3 | N1 | Y2 | S7 | S22 | 6 |
| 9 | 1 | P2 | X3 | S8 | *null* | *null* |
| 10 | 2 | X3 | N1 | S33 | S8 | 9 |
| 11 | 3 | N1 | Y1 | S9 | S33 | 10 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ez-Xp4Wn)